# Strange Error: ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I found a strange behavior and hope someone has an explanation for it.  I'm doing:

```
if len(list) > 1 and len(list2) > 1:
   total = sum(list) + sum(list2)
   result = percentage(sum(list), total)

def percentage(part, whole):
    return float(part) / float(whole) *100
```

The two lists are a mix of float and int values.  I sporadically get:

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

This doesn't makes sense to me. Does anyone have an idea what's happening?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear? Are you wondering *how* `whole` can be set to 0?

Comment: Show us your input!

Comment: yes the message is clear but doesn't make sense since the "whole" is the sum of both lists. So the only case a division by 0 can happen is if  both lists have a sum of zero and than the math would be 0/0 which should not throw an error right?

Comment: type `0/0` in the console and see if it throws an error. Try `0.0/0.0` too.

Comment: Have you tried simple debugging: print("Whole is:" + whole).  Empty lists are going to sum to zero...

Comment: Ohhh Boy ok 0/0 Throws the error but to be honest it doesn't makes sense to me since this is a case where just 0 should be returned....
anyways thanks for the comments!

Comment: 0 / 0 isn't even mathematically defined. You can extend x/0.0 (x != 0) to mean infinite in a suitable number system (which python doesn't support by default).  0 / 0 can only be defined in terms of limits, and then it depends on the formula, just not the results. What would you expect it to return?

Comment: @max i would expect to get a 0

Comment: Assuming you've studied some calculus, lim x-> 0 x/x is 1 (which in some senses is zero over zero).  By changing the formula, you can get answer you want for 0 / 0, so it is undefined.  Some math libraries will return float('nan'), but Python's default floats is not one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is obvious if you print out the values of `part` and `whole` that caused this error to occur.

The solution is to handle any Division by Zero errors like so

```
       try:
           result = percentage(sum(list), total)
       except ZeroDivisionError:
           # Handle the error in whatever way makes sense for your application
```

Alternatively, you can check for zero before you divide

```
def percentage(part,whole):
    if whole == 0:
        if part == 0:
            return float("nan")
        return float("inf")
    return float(part) / float(whole) *100
```

(Thank you Joran Beasley and Max for making this mathematically correct)

Comment: `return float("inf")` you mean ;P

Comment: or float("nan"), assuming part is also zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use try/exception:

```
if len(list) > 1 and len(list2) > 1:
           total = sum(list) + sum(list2)
           result = percentage(sum(list), total)

        def percentage(part,whole):
            while True: 
                try:
                    return float(part) / float(whole) * 100
                except ValueError as e:
                    print(e)
```

This will not quit the program due to the error, it will just print the error.